# ¿Otra forma de seleccionar el máximo de una columna sin el MAX()? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Saludos a la comunidad.

Tengo una duda sobre sacar el máximo de una columna, pero de otra forma, yo he intentado la siguiente forma:

```sql
USE bdprueba
GO

SELECT MAX(M1.TotalDeber) MaxTotalDeber, M1.DocIdentidad, M1.NomCliente
FROM MOCK_DATA M1 JOIN MOCK_DATA M2 ON M1.DocIdentidad = M2.DocIdentidad
GROUP BY M1.DocIdentidad, M1.NomCliente
```

Y sí me resulta, el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: Resultado1]

---

Ahora bien, procedo a explicar:

- Tengo una tabla que es la siguiente:

[image: Tabla1]

- Requiero el máximo valor de la columna `TotalDeber` por cada cliente; como ven, una forma sencilla de hacerlo es cómo la consulta que coloqué; sin embargo aquí viene mi problema.
- Antes dejar en claro que esta tabla es una simulación de datos de una consulta más grande que tengo. La columna `TotalDeber` proviene en realidad de otra tabla y para su cálculo la consulta original es más o menos así:

```sql
SELECT tabla1.Identidad, tabla1.CodIdentidad, 
   SUM(SELECT total FROM otraTabla WHERE condicion='1') TotalDeber
FROM tabla1 JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1.identidad = tabla2.identidad
GROUP BY tabla1.Identidad, tabla1.CodIdentidad
```

- Como se puede ver el `TotalDeber` proviene en realidad del uso de `SUM()` y por tanto no me permitiría hacer uso del `MAX()` y ese es mi verdadero problema, por que requiero si o sí el máximo de esa columna por cliente y que el resultado sea tal cual este: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1bh3.png)

Entonces, mi problema y consulta es: ¿Qué otra forma existe de sacar el máximo `TotalDeber` por columna sin la posibilidad de usar el `MAX()`? Y sin usar bucles, porque ya he probado y eso incrementa muchísimo el tiempo de ejecución.

Gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En ese caso puedes convertir la primera consulta en una subconsulta y ahí usar el `MAX`

```
SELECT Identidad, CodIdentidad, MAX(TotalDeber) as TotalDeber
FROM (
         SELECT tabla1.Identidad,
                tabla1.CodIdentidad,
                SUM(SELECT total FROM otraTabla WHERE condicion = '1') TotalDeber
         FROM tabla1
                  JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1.identidad = tabla2.identidad
         GROUP BY tabla1.Identidad, tabla1.CodIdentidad
     ) t
GROUP BY Identidad, CodIdentidad
```

Comment: Me resultó. Muchas gracias.